# Xamarin Image From Bytearray - prevent Stream from closing?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

for my Xamarin App I use a Rest API Backend.
From the Backend I get pictures as bytearrays.

When I did not have the backend, I took local pictures via

```
ImageSource.FromResource(..)
```

and everything was fine.
With the bytearrays, I switched to

```
ImageSource.FromStream(..)
```

This worked fine in the first place as well. Lets say I show an Image on Page A.
When I load the data from the rest api and fill the ImageSource, everything looks good.
Than I navigate to Page B (via Shell) and back to Page A.

Now the following error occurs:

```
System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a closed Stream.'
```

It seems that the stream closed (which is normal C# behaviour).
But I wonder what I can do now so my App does not crash when navigating.
It is not an option to always call the backend when the page appears, because a huge amount of data could occur.

The only option I found was to store the pictures as base64 string and when page A appears I recreate all the Image Sources with fresh streams. Obviously this is bad performance and horrible coding.

Does anyone have an Idea how I can solve this?

If you need any more details (code or context), please comment.

Thanks alot in advance!
**Edit 1**
On IOS it works - just not on android.

**Edit 2**

It has definetly something to do with the Shell!

The code from @Wendy Zang - MSFT works, thanks for that! But as soon if I try the same code when navigating in a shell, it does not.

Any further ideas?
(Here the code i used to test. What you cannot see is that the "Cannot access a closed Stream" - Error occures)

```
public partial class AboutPage : ContentPage
    {
        public byte[] ImageData { get; set; }
        public AboutPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                ImageData = client.DownloadData("https://aka.ms/campus.jpg");
            }

            var stream1 = new MemoryStream(ImageData);
            image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream1);
        }
    }
```

XAML:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <Button Clicked="Button_Clicked" Text="Download" />
        <Image x:Name="image" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: cache the images to disk once you download them.  Or look into FFImageLoading, which will do it for you.

Comment: You could try to create a property to store the bytearrays and then set the property to imageSource.

Comment: @Jason I tried FFImageLoading Objects iwhout success, but maybe the wrong ones? Do you mean the typical "CachedImage"? If not, please give me a hint, thanks you! :)

Comment: @Wendy I tried it out. as far as I know there is no possibility to make a bytearray as Image Source without converting via stream. I did the following in the OnPropertyChanged-Method:
`var stream1 = new MemoryStream(ImageBytes);
ItemImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream1);`

but still have the same Error.

Answer (score 4):

Stream is already closed when function get called. Make a new stream inside of the passed function to the FromStream method:

```
image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(_imageData));
```

whole file:

```
public partial class AboutPage : ContentPage
{
    private byte[] _imageData;

    public AboutPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        if (_imageData == null)
        {
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                _imageData = client.DownloadData("https://aka.ms/campus.jpg");
            }
        }

        image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(_imageData));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the image byte array which download from the url. And then save the byte array to imageData property. When i navigetes to another page, the image could be seen without the error.

xaml:

```
 <ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <Button Clicked="Button_Clicked" Text="Download" />
        <Image x:Name="image" />
        <Button Text="Navigate" Clicked="Navigate_Clicked" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Code Behind:

```
public byte[] ImageData { get; set; }
    public Page20()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            ImageData = client.DownloadData("https://aka.ms/campus.jpg");
        }

        var stream1 = new MemoryStream(ImageData);
        image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream1);
    }


    private void Navigate_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Navigation.PushAsync(new Pages.Page21());
    }
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for you work! I testet the code and it works, but the error occures as soon as I use shell navigation (see my edits above)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the full image url why not use [UriImageSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.uriimagesource?view=xamarin-forms) and bind the url to your `ImageView`

Comment: It is just an Exmaple. In the real situation I get the picture as bytearray from the backend,

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, you have to initialize Stream in the OnAppearing () method.

> protected override void OnAppearing() {  var stream1 = new
> MemoryStream(ImageData);  image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
> stream1);  }